# CAST VARCHAR to XML including < (&lt;) , > (&gt;)

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, xml, t-sql

I am reading HTML data as XML.But due to some special character I am not able to do it.

Here was my original question:
[Using SQL read html data as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082220/using-sql-read-html-data-as-xml/52086149#52086149)

```
;WITH CTE AS
 (
 select 1 AS NUM ,'<BODY><TD> values = 100 </TD></BODY>' AS TES
 union
 select 2,'<BODY><TD>  values  < 100 </TD></BODY>'
 )
 select NUM
 , CAST(TES AS XML)
 from CTE
```

I am getting XML parsing error. I can't replace all < & > characters as, I need to traverse using that tags.

```
XML parsing: line 1, character 22, illegal qualified name character
```

Can you please help me on this ?

I found using regular expression I can do this. Can anyone help me to create regular expression for this?
Regular expressoin inside TSQL demo :
[dbo.RegexReplace](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/)

Comment: Would `select 2, '<BODY><TD>  values  &lt; 100 </TD></BODY>'` work?

Comment: Where is the text `'  values  < 100 '` coming from? If you have the string `'<BODY><TD>  values  < 100 </TD></BODY>'` already stored in your data engine, it's a little too late, you need to replace the special characters before you put it in the markup. So `'  values  < 100 '` becomes `'  values  &lt; 100 '` and then but your markup around it.

Comment: i can't change source.

Comment: Then you'll need to use *something else* to clean your data. SQL Server is not the right tool to fix bad markup languages.

Comment: Python is well suited for this. lookup BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is very strict. I doubt, that it is a good idea to use a *naked* `<` in pure html either, but this seems to work...

If your text is always between `<td>` tags (and there are not other tags in between), you might try to use a string replace to push your *broken* data into a `CDATA` section.

Try it out...

```
;WITH CTE AS
 (
 select 1 AS NUM ,'<BODY><TD> values = 100 </TD></BODY>' AS TES
 union
 select 2,'<BODY><TD>  values  < 100 </TD></BODY>'
 )
 ,replaced AS
 (
    SELECT NUM 
          ,REPLACE(REPLACE(TES,'<TD>','<TD><![CDATA['),'</TD>',']]></TD>') AS TES_new 
    FROM cte
 )
 select NUM
 , CAST(TES_new AS XML)
 from replaced;
```

This will replace all forbidden characters implicitly...